# binary search in python weird behavior

Tags: python, binary-search

Please look at this code:

```
def chop(array, search):
        lo = 0
        high = len(array) - 1
        while lo <= high:
                mid = (high + lo) /2
                if array[mid] == search:
                        return 'true'
                elif search > array[mid]:
                        low = mid + 1
                else:
                        high = mid - 1
        return 'false'



if __name__ == '__main__':
        a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        print chop(a, 3)
```

I wrote this little script which is supposed to search for number in array - regular binary search. So I run the script, and for example when I put in `chop(a, 1)` I get true, when I put in `chop(a, 2)` I get true, but when I put `chop(a, 3)` I don't get an answer, just empty line in the Python Shell.

Does anyone have an idea on what is going on?

Comment: `'true'` and `'false'`? What about [`True` and `False`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values)?

Comment: Your binary search is stalling when mid = 1.  Try printing the value of mid within your loop.

Comment: There is a similar function in the bisect module

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing this is your bug:

```
low = mid + 1
```

Your while loop uses the variable `lo`, and you're defining a new variable called `low` within your while loop. In essence, you're never updating your `lo` variable.

Change that line to:

```
lo = mid + 1
```

and your algorithm should work.

Comment: That's it. I can't believe I didn't notice it! Thanks

Comment: Happens to the best of us :) No worries

Comment: Ah, this is why I dont like python's declarations. Easy to miss.