# Infinite loop in binary search

Tags: python, infinite-loop, binary-search

I am trying to implement binary search   with the following function:

```
def buggy_binary_search(input, key):
    low = 0
    high = len(input)-1
    mid = (low + high)/2
    while low <= high:
        if input[mid] == key:
            return mid
        if input[mid] > key:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid
    return -1
```

The above function when run, gets into a infinite loop. How can I correct that?

Comment: You should update mid within the while loop

Comment: should I update the low value??@Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: you should put "mid = (low + high)/2" into the while loop; you should update low and high values (that you do) as well

Comment: check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918348/binary-search-in-python-weird-behavior?rq=1

Comment: let me tell you something, print low, high inside while loop and see, whether the values are updated or not, after you can possibly think where to change it.

Comment: It should be `low = mid + 1` also in the `else` condition, apart from updating `mid` in the while loop.

Comment: Note that python has a `bisect` module that implements binary search. I suggest you to read its source code. The module implements both "right" binary search and "left" binary search, i.e. searches that always return the rightmost or leftmost occurrence of the element. (it's under `Lib/bisect.py` in the python sources).

Comment: You can accept my answer as it is solving your problem. It is considered a bad practice on SO to not accept answers that are correct and provide solution to your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you are not updating the value of `mid` the while loop keeps on checking the same element and runs into an infinite loop, to correct that as many people have pointed out, update `mid` in the while loop.
Also, you should do `low = mid+1` and not `low = mid`.

The full code is given below:-

```
    def binary_search(input, key):
       low = 0
       high = len(input)-1
       mid = (low + high)/2
       while low <= high:
          mid = (low + high)/2
          if input[mid] == key:
             return mid
          if input[mid] > key:
             high = mid - 1
          else:
             low = mid + 1
       return -1
```

Make sure the input is sorted!

Comment: In python 2 what if `high == sys.maxint`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def binary_search(input, key):
    low = 0
    high = len(input)-1
    mid = (low + high)/2
    while low <= high:
       mid = (low + high)/2
       if input[mid] == key:
           return mid
       if input[mid] > key:
           high = mid - 1
       else:
           low = mid + 1
    return -1
```

as Dmitry Bychenko said, you should put mid = (low + high)/2 in the loop.

Comment: what's the data in input?

Comment: @Ramya is your `input` sorted in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Since the item isn't in `input[mid]`, the range should be adjusted so `low = mid + 1`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right, `low = mid+1` is correct, should be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""don't use "input" as a variable name. its a python keyword.
make sure your array is sorted
use integer division when computing midpoint
"""

def bsearch(input_array,target):
    lo,hi=0,len(input_array)-1
    while lo<=hi:
        mid=(lo+hi)//2
        if input_array[mid]==target:
            print "found at ",mid
            return mid
        if input_array[mid]>target:
            print "look left"
            hi=mid-1
        if input_array[mid]<target:
            print "look right"
            lo=mid+1
    return -1

a=[2,4,7,8,12,88,99,101]
target=7

assert bsearch(a,1134)==-1,"value 1134 isn't in array but says it is"
assert bsearch(a,2)==0,"value 2 is in the zero element of array.begenning"
assert bsearch(a,101)==7,"value 101 is in the 7th element of array. end"
assert bsearch(a,12)==4,"value 12 is in the 4th element of array. midpoint"
```